# Seeking LiDAR data processing and analysing tool?

Tags: software-recommendations, lidar

I am working on Lidar VLP-16.

Can you advise me about the open source software that I could use for processing the lidar data and extract the object from the data?

Comment: R and the lidR library: https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki

Comment: @BERA great option! I didn't know it. You could post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

[R](https://www.r-project.org/) and the [lidR library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/index.html):

> Airborne LiDAR (Light Detection and Ranging) interface for data
>   manipulation and visualization. Read/write 'las' and 'laz' files,
>   computation of metrics in area based approach, point filtering,
>   artificial point reduction, classification from geographic data,
>   normalization, individual tree segmentation and other manipulations.

Examples: [How to quickly learn lidR](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki)